# <fb:comments-count> not working on my WordPress powered blog

Tags: facebook, comments, wordpress, facebook-fql

I am using the Facebook comments plugin on WordPress and the comments box is working fine but I want to access the number of counts on the index page and on single pages. On the pages, the Facebook Javascript is loaded on the pages.

Here's the code I used:
`<fb:comments-count href=<?php echo get_permalink() ?>/></fb:comments-count> comments`

But it doesn't count the FB comments.

Is there a simple code that let me retrieve the number of comment counts?

Thanks,

Comment: This is resolved. I used <fb:comments href= in place of <fb:comments url=. The only difference was using href instead of url that made it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include this function somewhere in your **template file** :

```
function fb_comment_count() {

    global $post;
    $url = get_permalink($post->ID);

    $filecontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
    $json = json_decode($filecontent);
    $count = $json->$url->comments;
    if ($count == 0 || !isset($count)) {
        $count = 0;
    }
    echo $count;
}
```

use it like this in your homepage or wherever

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php fb_comment_count() ?></a>
```

Had the same problem, that function worked for me... if you get an error... try reading [this](http://paragonhost.wordpress.com/2009/02/27/url-file-access-is-disabled-in-the-server-configuration/).

Comment: The code works, but throws some warnings when there are no comments. Fixed by replacing the last lines (after "$json = ...") with this: `return empty($json->$url->comments) ? 0 : (int) $json->$url->comments;`

Answer (score 2):

The comments often don't appear here :

```
graph.facebook.com/?ids = [your url]
```

Instead they appear well in

```
graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids = [your url]
```

Hence the value of the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by ifennec seems fine, but actually is not working (facebook maybe changed something and now is only returning the number of shares).

You could try to get all the comments:

```
    $filecontent = file_get_contents(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=' . $url);
```

And count all:

```
    $json = json_decode($filecontent);
    $content = $json->$url;
    $count = count($content->data);

    if (!isset($count) || $count == 0) {
       $count = 0;
    }
    echo $count;
```

This is just a fix until facebook decides to read the FAQ about fb:comments-count, and discovers it's not working :) (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ yeah, awesome comments).

By the way, I applied the function in Drupal 7 :) Thank you very much ifennec, you showed me the way.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

```
function fb_comment_count() {
  global $post;
  $url = get_permalink($post->ID);
  $filecontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=' . $url);
  $json = json_decode($filecontent);
  echo(count($json->$url->comments->data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.

```
<p><span class="cmt"><fb:comments-count href=<?php the_permalink(); ?>></fb:comments-count></span> Comments</p>
```

The problem was that I was using 'url' than a 'href' attribute in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this function in **functions.php** and pass the post url to **function fb_comment_count** wherever you call it on your theme files

```
function fb_comment_count($url) {
$filecontent    = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=' . $url);
$json           = json_decode($filecontent);
$content        = $json->$url;

echo count($content->comments->data);
```

}