# Facebook comments count incorrect

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

We're using Facebook comments on a Wordpress blog and the comment count returned by the following tag does not match the actual number of comments on the page.

```
<fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count>
```

You can see an example [here](http://www.civilbeat.com/2014/02/21257-gene-park-the-debate-over-race-history-and-racism-in-hawaii/) where the comment count returned is 168 even though there are only 2 comments on the page.

The Facebook Graph API returns the correct number of comments for this url as seen [here](https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.civilbeat.com/2014/02/21257-gene-park-the-debate-over-race-history-and-racism-in-hawaii/) but unfortunately using the count returned by the Graph API as demonstrated in the SO Post below is disallowed by our host WPEngine since the php.ini setting for allow_url_include must be set to off.

[<fb:comments-count> not working on my WordPress powered blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956488/fbcomments-count-not-working-on-my-wordpress-powered-blog)

Any ideas on what might be going wrong or another alternative for returning the correct comment count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example URL you mentioned is `http://www.civilbeat.com/2014/02/21257-gene-park-the-debate-over-race-history-and-racism-in-hawaii/`, whereas your code for the like count points to

```
<fb:comments-count href='http://www.civilbeat.com/posts/2014/02/21/21257-gene-
   park-the-debate-over-race-history-and-racism-in-hawaii/'>
```

That is a different URL than the one of the page - notice the extra `/posts/` part right after the domain name, that is not in the page URL you mentioned before. And if you check the second one via API, you see that it indeed has a comment count of 168.

Comment: Hey thanks, this really pointed me in the right direction. We recently migrated our site from Django to Wordpress and accordingly had to change the structure of our urls. We have a redirect from the old urls to the new urls and for some reason the comment count was using the old url while the comments themselves were not.